# designing css fluid/fixed layout with css and not using tables

Tags: css

how would you approach the design of the following layout without using any tables?

i have tried but cannot get the height of the 3 central div elements to 100% height.

[image]

any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: What's going in the background of the three central divs? Solid background colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very useful and easy solution I use for three equal height columns is the following: Make a wrapper which is positioned `relative` and with `height:100%`. Then all the children are positioned `absolute` and adding `height:100%`, will take the whole height of your wrapper. Because positioning them `absolute` will move it in the top-left side of your screen, you apply `margin-left` accordingly to move it in the right side of your browser.

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first" class="column"></div>
    <div id="second" class="column"></div>
    <div id="third" class="column"></div>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
body,html,#wrapper,.column {height:100%;}
  #wrapper {position:relative;}
  .column {position:absolute;border:1px solid black;width:33.3%}
  #second {margin-left:33.3%}
  #third {margin-left:66.6%}
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/igoso4

I have tested the above method in firefox,chrome,safari,ie 7,8+, opera.